# IE: nth-child() using odd/even isn't working

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-selectors, css-tables

My table (that works perfectly on Chrome, FireFox and Opera) is not displaying correctly on Internet Explorer.

The background remains white! (I am using IE-8)

**CSS code:**

```
/*My Table*/
.my_table{
border-collapse:collapse;
font:normal 14px sans-serif,tahoma,arial,verdana;
margin:5px 0;
}

.my_table th{
color:#fff;
background:#5E738A;
border:1px solid #3C5169;
text-align:center;
padding:4px 10px;
}

.my_table td{
color:#555;
border:1px solid #C1CAD4;
text-align:center;
padding:2px 5px;
}

.my_table tr:nth-child(even){
background:#E6EDF5;
}

.my_table tr:nth-child(odd){
background:#F0F5FA;
}
```

Comment: IE8 doesn't support `:nth-child()`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

IE8 doesn't support the `nth-child` selector I'm afraid:

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild

Answer (score 53):

As a good workaround, jQuery has added this to their project and achieving this using JavaScript is acceptable:

For my CSS, I would have

```
.my_table tr.even{
    background:#E6EDF5;
}

.my_table tr.odd{
    background:#F0F5FA;
}
```

And I would use jQuery to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".my_table tr:nth-child(even)").addClass("even");
    $(".my_table tr:nth-child(odd)").addClass("odd");
});
```

Comment: this is the real answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can use first-child and "+" to emulate nth-child, example:

```
tr > td:first-child + td + td + td + td + td + td + td + td {
    background-color: red;
}
```

That select the 9th column, just like nth-child(9), and that works on IE

Comment: Holy crap, that’s one hell of a selector!

Comment: This would only work if you know exactly which element you are targeting. The desired effect is to select every odd, and every even, `tr`, despite the number of total `tr`.

Comment: DV: I can't get this working. Can someone make a working fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

This is the Dojo version, it works fine:

```
  dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
      dojo.query("table tr:nth-child(odd)").addClass("odd");
      dojo.query("table tr:nth-child(even)").addClass("even");
  });
```

Comment: I have never written in dojo, but it doesn't seem right that one line uses `addClass` while the other uses `addStyle`

Comment: That was a typo in my posting, the correct way is using **addClass**. Thanks for pointing it out. I edited the posting, now it shows the correct way for both.

Answer (score 1):

I made some time ago, a prude simple javascript solution for this *problem*:

https://gist.github.com/yckart/5652296

```
var nthChild = function (elem, num) {
    var len = elem.length;
    var ret = [];
    var i = 0;

    // :nth-child(num)
    if (!isNaN(Number(num))) {
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (i === num - 1) return elem[i];
        }
    }

    // :nth-child(numn+num)
    if (num.indexOf('+') > 0) {
        var parts = num.match(/\w/g);
        for (i = parts[2] - 1; i < len; i += parts[0] << 0) {
            if (elem[i]) ret.push(elem[i]);
        }
    }

    // :nth-child(odd)
    if (num === 'odd') {
        for (i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            ret.push(elem[i]);
        }
    }

    // :nth-child(even)
    if (num === 'even') {
        for (i = 1; i < len; i += 2) {
            ret.push(elem[i]);
        }
    }

    return ret;
};
```

The usage is quite simple and similar to the css-selector:

```
var rows = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var num = nthChild(rows, 2);
var formula = nthChild(rows, '3n+1');
var even = nthChild(rows, 'even');
var odd = nthChild(rows, 'odd');


// Note, forEach needs to be polyfilled for oldIE
even.forEach(function (li) {
    li.className += ' even';
});

odd.forEach(function (li) {
    li.className += 'odd';
});

formula.forEach(function (li) {
    li.className += ' formula';
});

num.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/s3KLz/