# jQuery: nth-child selector not working in ie7

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7, css-selectors

So I've got a grid of divs, not all equal heights and I need them all to line up properly. I've used the nth-child jQuery selector (see below) to select the first div of each row and apply a **clear:both** style to it. This works in ie8 and up as well as chrome and safari however in ie7 it just ignores the nth-child bit and therefore doesn't apply my css.

I used jQuery over css3 so that it would work in ie7 - so am slighty baffled by the fact it's not..

See the html for yourself at http://jackbeck.co.uk/?portfolio=courses

jQuery code in header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('.project.small:nth-child(4n+1)').css("clear", "both");
    });
</script>'
```

Anyone able to help?

Comment: If all the thumbnails are just gonna line up one after each other, why do you need the clear:both? Wouldn't the float:left and the width of the container handle that for you?

Comment: You shouldn´t need any Javascript to solve this one.

Comment: If you are comfortable using Jquery then here is the solution. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8194206/175111

Answer (score 3):

YES; IE8 & below is not support `nth-child` pseudo selector. But if you want `IE support` than you have to use http://selectivizr.com/ js for this.

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery doesn't work because you're using `$` instead of `jQuery` (it's a WordPress thing). Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        jQuery('.project.small:nth-child(4n+1)').css("clear", "both");
    });
</script>
```

The jQuery selector itself does, in fact, work in IE7. That's not your issue. Your issue has more to do with CSS.

Comment: Ok thanks for your quick reply :) I made the change as you've suggested but still no joy - could there be anything else wrong?

Comment: Like I said, jQuery is not the problem.  The easiest solution would be to wrap every 4 projects into a `<div class="clearfix"></div>`. Scrap the jQuery/clear stuff. That should work.

Comment: Yes that would be ideal :) but is it possible to do that when each of the projects are generated by wordpress?

Comment: Anything's possible! You'll have to look into the template in your theme that prints out the projects and make the necessary changes there.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately IE7 [doesn't support](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t38) the `nth-child` selector.

Comment: While the `nth-child` selector doesn't work for CSS, it should work for jQuery.