# ODD/EVEN only two columns from the table

Tags: html, css, class, html-table

I would like to create such effect to change background ODD/EVEN to each `<TR>` only to fields with `class="important"`..
bellow it is an example of table... it is not static... it is created by PHP with data from Mysql...

```
<tr class="change">
   <td>1111</td>
   <td>2222</td>
   <td>3333</td>
   <td>4444</td>
   <td class="important">5555</td>
   <td class="important">6666</td>
<tr>
<tr class="change">
   <td>1111</td>
   <td>2222</td>
   <td>3333</td>
   <td>4444</td>
   <td class="important">5555</td>
   <td class="important">6666</td>
<tr>
```

So, I would like to have for each `<TR>` an ODD or EVEN effecting only few cells from tables based by CLASS IMPORTANT

Comment: This question is extremely unclear, hell it's barely even a question - it's closer to a statement at the moment.

Comment: `only few cells` how many? From left or right? What class(es)? Is the odd/even style change on cells or rows (or both)?

Comment: Do you mean this? http://jsfiddle.net/qxEaC/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```
tr.change:nth-child(even) td.important {
  background: #CCC;
}

tr.change:nth-child(odd) td.important {
  background: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: I have other tables in page that is affected by this code... need to modify the script based on CLASSES rather to TR:

Comment: Then change the selector beginnings to `tr.change`. Basic CSS actually.

Answer (score -1):

Try jQuery [odd](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) or [even](http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/) selector to accomplish this. You have to also check hasClass selector to check `important` class as well.

Comment: Yes, if someone using jqyery then he/she can achieve this easily in odd or even selector. Both way it works.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with DOM manipulation for what can easily be accomplished with plain old CSS.

Comment: Using jQuery for this is like doing math calculations on a paper having an electric calculator right there.

Comment: @ComFreek To be fair, the CSS methods are not as cross-browser compatible, so it depends on what browsers the OP wants this to work on.

Comment: @SmokeyPHP That's a valid point, but this should be also expressed in the answer itself (e.g. "you could use jQuery if you want to support IE <= 8"). Here is a full solution using jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8194206/603003