# Coloring a Partial view in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, css

In my view, I use a partial view with a list of objects from my model as follows:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.MyObjectList)
{
    @Html.Partial("DisplayObject", item)   
}
```

This forms a grid pattern down my main view, 1 row for each object.

I'd like to stripe them using normal method of odd rows one colour, even rows another. (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929538/c-sharp-mvc3-razor-alternating-items-in-a-foreach-list) for example.

Usually you'd do this by doing some kind of mod calculation.

The question is I can't figure out how to do this without passing in a row number in the item into the partial view.

Is there an easier way? Html.Partial does not have any html attributes I can hook into.

I could of course put a table around the partial and stripe it that way, but would prefer not to.

Comment: can you post the partial view code?

Comment: can you post the rendered html code.

Comment: largely irrelevant now as we have a number of answers, but thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can limit support to CSS3 you can use the `:nth-child(odd)` and `:nth-child(even)` rules - as shown on this page from W3C - http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

Those examples show how to use it on `tr` tags - but it applies to anything that you can apply a selector to:

```
<style type="text/css">
  div p:nth-child(odd) { color:red; }
  div p:nth-child(even) { color:green; }
</style>
<div>
  <p>first</p>
  <p>second</p>
  <p>third</p>
</div>
```

Comment: define 'all browsers'.  Are you planning on having an [IE7 tax](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-18440979)?  Or indeed an IE8 tax?  Otherwise, you've got IE9+ and the others.  [Check it on Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)

Comment: I mean majority of the browsers not *all*

Comment: Isn't it!? I'm seriously thinking of recommending it to management!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should pass the information in the model that is passed to the partial view OR wrap the partial view in an element and apply the correct css to it...like:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.MyObjectList) {
    <li class="odd|even">
    @Html.Partial("DisplayObject", item)  
    </li>  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the row number as a property to the definition of your class that defines each 'item'.

Use that property in the partial view to determine if its an odd or even row.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `Mode` value through `ViewBag` from the main view to partial.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.MyObjectList) 
{
    if(ViewBag.Mode == "odd")
    {
       ViewBag.Mode = "even";
    }
    else
    {
      ViewBag.Mode = "odd";
    }

    @Html.Partial("DisplayObject", item)  
}
```